# How to refactor to a higher order function?

Tags: javascript, refactoring, higher-order-functions

How to refactor this function to a higher order function?

It is meant to return a new array containing the sub-arrays of **characters** that contain the value 'Rambo'.

```
function isRamboCharacter(characters) {

 const x = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    if (characters[i].movie.includes('Rambo')) {
      x.push(characters[i]);
    }
  }

return x;
}
```

I tried:

```
return characters.movie.includes('Rambo');
```

Comment: hint - the function you want here is `filter`

Comment: Could you explain what this "higher order function" is meant to do, and how it's meant to be used? Add some example input data, and your expected output. And welcome to SO.

Comment: Do you mean `isRamboCharacter` to *become* a higher-order function itself, or to *use* more higher-order functions in its implementation?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```js
const characters = [
    { movie: ["Rambo", "Rockey", "Avengers"] }, 
    { movie: ["Fatherhood", "Rockey", "Avengers"] }
 ]
    
const isRamboCharacter = (characters) => characters.filter((char) => char.movie.includes("Rambo"))

console.log(isRamboCharacter(characters));
```

**Or you could directly call Array's filter method**

```js
console.log(characters.filter((char) => char.movie.includes("Rambo")));

//output - [ { movie: [ 'Rambo', 'Rockey', 'Avengers' ] } ]
```

Comment: It really depends on what dataset that the OP hasn't provided looks like. The dataset you've assumed here doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can curry it (Return a function in a function)

```
function isCharacterInMovie(movie) {
  return function filterFunction(characters) {
    const x = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
      if (characters[i].movie.includes(movie)) {
        x.push(characters[i]);
      }
    }
    return x;
  }
}
const isRamboInMovie = isCharacterInMovie('rambo') // returns the inner function which holds on to the value from when you called it
 isRamboInMovie(charactersInTheMatrix); // []
 isRamboInMovie(charactersInRambo); // ['rambo']
```

The 'You don't know JS' book series has a great (short AND free) book on this, and it explains it incredibly well
[You Don't Know JS Yet: Scope & Closures - 2nd Edition](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/README.md)